# Qt Mobility or Qt Location available for desktop use?

Tags: qt, geospatial, qt5, qt-mobility

I have been trying to implement a mapviewer application in Qt as a desktop applicaation to work with multi-touch. I'd been having some trouble when I came across mention of [Qt Mobility](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt-mobility/location-overview.html). Qt Mobility seems to be an old module that was used on mobile devices but doesn't appear to be supported by Nokia anymore. Although there is a [active repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility).

From what I can gather from various more recent forum posts such as [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23712) is if we want to use Qt Mobility's Location features we need to wait for it to be released in newer versions of Qt.

If the Qt Mobility api is still available through the repository is it possible to use this for desktop applications or is it strictly for mobile devices? I am interested in making use of the Qt Location classes to help create a map viewer client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QtMobility API while deprecated is still being updated and is still available and according to a [thread on the Qt Developers it should work with Qt 4.8](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-July/011873.html) (it was only officially supported up until Qt 4.7). According to the documentation it can be used for desktop applications, but they are [mostly tier 2 platforms](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt-mobility/index.html#platform-compatibility).

While Qt Location won't be ready until Qt 5.2 ([expected at the end of November](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-August/012483.html)), I wouldn't expect it to drop support for platforms that are already supported in QtMobility.